# Throwing exception when object in array doesn't have expected property

Tags: ruby, arrays, exception

I'm fairly new to ruby and I've written a scraper, that scrapes car websites. I have an array, which is supposed to have car, but seem to have some unexpected objects in the array because of the scraping. I do the following in my code:

```
car_manufacture = car_array.map{|c| c.manufacture}
```

Now sometimes I the objects in the `car_array` are not actually car objects and don't have a manufacture property. When this is the case I would like to throw an exception and log the object. I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Here are somethings I've tried:

```
car_array.map{|c| c.manufacture}.each{|c| !c.manufacture raise RuntimeError, "Error: Unknown object"}
```

And it doesn't seem to be working. Ideally I would like to have the exception thrown and logged and just continue moving on. Essentially just ignoring the object in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `partition` to split those out and track what didn't have the information.

```
with, without = car_array.partition { |car| !!car.manufacture }
```

Now you have 2 arrays, `with` contains cars where `manufacture` had something, and `without` contains ones that didn't.  Log or throw as you see fit.

You can now safely get the manufacture as well:

```
car_manufacture = with.map(&:manufacture)
```